# How to make sure that a 'path' holds the same x and y position when dragged into a different div

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a SVG container (Canvas), which has an SVG path (leftLeg) in it. When I drag the SVG path into another div (save), the path goes somewhere else and doesnt hold the position where I dragged it? How Can I solve this? I am using the following libraries:
http://svgdiscovery.com/SVGjs/Plugins/svg.draggable.js
http://svgdiscovery.com/SVGjs/Plugins/svg.connectable.js

I have the following code:

```
<style>             
 #canvas {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #cccccc;
 }


<svg id = "canvas" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" z-index="100">
        <svg id="dropzone" pointer-events="all" overflow="visible" width="400" height="350" x="90" y="10" fill="white">
            <text x="102" y="-2" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="5px" font-weight="bold" fill="black">Drop here</text>      
            <rect id="dropzoneBox" x="100" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="3"></rect>
        </svg>  

        <svg id = "save"  x="190" y="10" width="200" height="175" overflow="visible">
              <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" fill-opacity="0" />
        </svg>
</svg>


    var canvas = SVG('canvas');
    save = SVG('save');

    function dragIntoBoard(event) {
        console.log(event);
        
        //http://svgjs.dev/referencing/#circular-reference
        var node = event.target,
            svg = node.instance;

        var e = event.detail.event,
            posX = e.clientX,
            posY = e.clientY,
            box = save.node.getBoundingClientRect();

        //If the element is dropped on top of #save,
        //we move the element from the #canvas wrapper into #save:
        if( (box.left <= posX) && (posX <= box.right) &&
            (box.top <= posY)  && (posY <= box.bottom) ) {

            save.add(svg);
        
            //Make the circle's position relative to #save, not #canvas:
            svg.cx(svg.cx() - save.x());
            svg.cy(svg.cy() - save.y());

            //No need to listen for more dragging:
            svg.off('dragend.namespace');
        }
    }

    function leftLeg()
    {
     var lines = canvas.group();
     lines.attr({"stroke-width":1})
            var markers = canvas.group();
            var nodes = canvas.group();
            var g1 = nodes.group().translate(50, 100).draggable();
            g1.circle(1.5).fill("#000");
            var g2 = nodes.group().translate(50, 120).draggable();
            g2.circle(1.5).fill("#000");
            var g3 = nodes.group().translate(50, 140).draggable();
            g3.circle(1.5).fill("#000");
            g1.connectable({  //---main, central element---
                container: lines,
               markers: markers
            }, g2).setLineColor("#000");
            g2.connectable({
            }, g3).setLineColor("#000")
        var group = canvas.group()
        group.add(lines)
        group.add(g1)
        group.add(g2)
        group.add(g3)
                        
        group.draggable();
        group.on('dragend.namespace', dragIntoBoard);   
    }
```